# Communicate between 2 google chrome processes (tabs) with javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, google-chrome, process, communication

**Question:**

What is the best way to communicate between separate Google Chrome rendering processes (tabs) without the use of a web-server?

**Background:**

I am writing a large application and recently I decided to try and migrate the whole thing to the browser. Due to where I work this is Google Chrome. Previous the application consisted of a c++ based (Qt) webserver / calculation engine and the browser was only used for the GUI. Now I have moved the calculation engine to javascript and I run it in the browser.

The problem is that the GUI is slightly unstable. It will often stay running for about 12 hours but then crash with an "Aw Snap" error. Before I wasn't worried because it was a simple matter of refreshing the page. Now when the GUI crashes because it is running in the same process as the calculation engine, that crashes also.

**Details:**

The calculation engine is now a web-page that spawns a number of web-workers. It also opens the GUI (a separate webpage) as a popup window and communicates to it using PostMessage.

The GUI typically needs to read ~ 500 floating point numbers / second (sent as JSON) from the calculation engine and write back ~ 5 numbers / second.

Yesterday I got excited because I discovered the SharedWorker API which I thought would accomplish was I wanted. Today however, I learned that recently modifications were made to Chrome so the SharedWorker actually runs in the same process as the attached tabs and it actually forces all the tabs attached to it into one process. Apparently it didn't used to do this. Does anyone know if there are any browser flags that I can set to revert to the old behavior?

I also have read a little bit about ServiceWorkers and other new APIs such as WebRTC. I have also played around with the storage APIs and thought that maybe they could be used to get two separate processes (tabs) to communicate at the rates that I need.

I want a solution that will work locally (using switches like --allow-file-access-from-files) and that doesn't require plugin installation (since even local plugins are blocked where I work).

NOTE: I saw some other similar questions but they didn't specifically address the need for there to be separate processes (only separate tabs)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like I figured out the answer already. The problem turned out to be how I was trying to open the GUI window.

I had a link on the calculation engine that the user clicked on to open the window:

```
<a href="gui.html" target="_blank">Open GUI</a>
```

However, it turns out that adding `rel="noreferrer"` will cause chrome to open the window in a new process.

```
<a href="gui.html" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">Open GUI in new process</a>
```

After I figured this out, the SharedWorker began to function as I had expected and I was able to keep by engine tab running even when the GUI tab crashed.